# ngModelGroup inside ngFor?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ngmodel, angular2-ngmodel

How can I retrieve the validation status of an `NgModelGroup` that is nested within an `NgFor`?

If I don't have the `NgFor`, I can assign the group to a template variable like this:

```
<p *ngIf="addressCtrl.invalid">Address is invalid.</p>

<div ngModelGroup="address" #addressCtrl="ngModelGroup">
    <input name="city"  [ngModel]="address.city"  required>
    <input name="state" [ngModel]="address.state" required>
    <input name="zip"   [ngModel]="address.zip"   required>
</div>
```

But instead I want to have something like this:

```
<p *ngIf="addressCtrl.invalid">Address # {{index}} is invalid.</p>

<div *ngFor="let address of addresses">
    <div ngModelGroup="address" #addressCtrl="ngModelGroup">
        <input name="city"  [ngModel]="address.city"  required>
        <input name="state" [ngModel]="address.state" required>
        <input name="zip"   [ngModel]="address.zip"   required>
    </div>
</div
```

The problem is that I get `addressCtrl` is undefined.

Here is a plunker I created to test this with: https://plnkr.co/edit/RXi2T52kynsWLr4fDMVa?p=preview

Comment: Is it working, what is the error?

Comment: no it couldnt possibly work how would it know which control i want? The current error is that the control is undefined. i will update question

Comment: Have you tried using reactive forms? If you do so, all your logic will be inside the component, you will have an object with all fields and validation states (valid, dirty, pristine...) on each one, and you will be able to set a property based on them.

Comment: You're trying to get status from array of groups. What is the purpose? What it the expected behavior?

Comment: @yurzui, the purpose/use case is: I have a complex form with a variable number of these "form groups". in another portion of the form template (higher up and outside of the *ngFor) I would like to display the validation status of these groups

Answer (score 7):

```
addressHistory valid? {{ myHistoryGroup.valid }}
<ul ngModelGroup="addressHistory" #myHistoryGroup="ngModelGroup">
    <li *ngFor="let i = index; let address of addressHistory">
        <div [ngModelGroup]="i" #myLi="ngModelGroup">
        address valid? {{ myLi.valid }}
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="address.state" name="state" />
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="address.country" name="country" />
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<!--
#myForm.value will be like this:

{ "addressHistory": { "0": { ... }, "1": { ... }}, ... }
-->
```

Yes you can, use it like this.

Comment: there is no way yet to get the list of elements of 'addressHistory' in the shape of an array?

Comment: @LaszloSarvold What do you mean? There is a For-Loop around the 'addressHistory' `*ngFor="let i = index; let address of addressHistory"`. It is already like an array.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, I meant like `{ "addressHistory": [ "0": { ... }, "1": { ... } ] , ... }`. I have just moved to reactive forms due to not being provided out of the box with template driven forms.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to work fine, if you move

```
<p *ngIf="addressCtrl.invalid">Address # {{index}} is invalid.</p>
```

inside your iteration.

Your plunker has a bit different code, so there it would be:

```
<p *ngIf="group.invalid">Address # {{index}} is invalid.</p>
```

Your forked

### [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/kuhGQYQtT9bRuSlggnDm?p=preview)

Comment: This of course means that the error message is shown in each address fieldset, maybe that is not your desired result?

Comment: yes of course it will work fine within the iteration, because there angular knows which ngModelGroup you mean since you are within that scope. The question is how to access from outside the iteration

Comment: Yes, I understand that now. That occurred to me after posting, therefore my comment. Your post didn't explicitly mention that, so that is probably why it got overlooked by me. Sorry for wasting your time.